# Laravel - I can't access variables in my View sent from my Controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I've uploaded one of my sites to Laravel forge running on `Digital Ocean` and the site's views couldnt access  variables sent from the `Controller`. So I thought I would try a new install of `Laravel`:

**Controller Method:**

```
 public function showWelcome()
 {
     return View::make('hello')->with(['test1'=>2,'test3'=>'fotune']);
 }
```

**View :**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Laravel PHP Framework</title>
    <style>
        ...
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="welcome">
        <a href="http://laravel.com" title="Laravel PHP Framework">
            <img src="..." alt="Laravel PHP Framework">
        </a>
        <h1>You have arrived.</h1>
        <h1>{{$test1}}</h1>
        <h1>{{$test3}}</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**The error/exception I get:**

```
Undefined variable: test1 (View: /home/forge/default/app/views/hello.blade.php)
```

Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: It should work, try `artisan clear-compiled` then dump autoload again, clear cached views etc. The code you have is correct.

Comment: Are you running at least PHP 5.4.0?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$data = array('test1'=>2, 'test3' => 'fotune');
return View::make('hello')->with('data',$data);
```

In your view:

```
{{$data[test1]}}
{{$data[test3]}}
```

or also you can try:

```
return View::make('hello')->with('data',['test1'=>2,'test3'=>'fotune']);
```

In your view:

```
{{$data[test1]}}
{{$data[test3]}}
```

Comment: @TheAlpha It will work, however I wouldn't go this way.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove test1 variable, you get the same error?
Have you tried put 2 in quotes like

```
return View::make('hello')->with(['test1'=>'2','test3'=>'fotune']);
```